# Blender animation error. When the camera moves through a transparent object, there is an extra frame visible. How to get rid of that?

Tags: rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine

When I pass the camera through the globe, there is a glitch, an extra frame is visible in the middle. How do I get rid of the same?

The error https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_TrlvmGS67kVL7odm2W6ugnwpyPmpOiN/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Could it be that the camera is inside the glass of the globe for one frame, I mean between the outer and the inner wall? Then I guess it's the refraction that distorts differently inside glass than outside.

Comment: Yes, it's inside the glass of the globe for one frame as the camera would be passing through the globe from inside. I'm trying to get rid of that frame and get a smooth transition.

Comment: I don't know how far your camera moves from one frame to the next. So, solutions would be to either place the dome slightly different, or change the thickness of the glass or the timing of the camera movement so that it's inside on one frame and outside on the next. Or you have to adjust the _Clip Start_ value in the camera settings so that the glass wall will be invisible in the moment where the camera is inside.